# Switch statement on Objective-C not working

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I just learned how to use switch statements and I'm trying to implement it on my project but won't work.

```
int x;
    x = arc4random()%5;

    switch (x) {
        case '0':
            NSLog(@"0");

            break;
        case '1':
            NSLog(@"1");

            break;
        case '2':
            NSLog(@"2");
            break;
        case '3':
            NSLog(@"3");

            break;
        case '4':
            NSLog(@"4");

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
```

This is my line of code and I looked at multiple examples and I don't see anything wrong with my code.

I assume that it has something to do with it being inside the `viewDidLoad` because that is the only thing thats different between the examples I looked at and my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are testing against characters, not integer values.

You need to use `case 0`, `case 1` etc. without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the apostrophes and it should work properly. Adding apostrophes like `case '0':` makes it test for string inputs. Writing it like `case 0:` will make it test for integer inputs.

Comment: Single apostrophes (') will take it as a character, not a string. Quotes (") will treat it as a char pointer.